# Comparing 2 methods based on 2 sets of p-values

Tags: p-value, method-comparison

I have a method A that gives me 3 p-values (say p1A, p2A, p3A) for measuring 3 performance metrics. I have a method B that gives another set of 3 p-values (say p1B, p2B, p3B) for measuring the same set of 3 metrics. I want to get a single p-value (say pAB) showing that the method A does better than the method B. So, my null hypothesis is that "Method B does better than method A or they perform equally" and I want to reject this hypothesis if pAB is smaller than .05, for example. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are the "methods" statistical analyses that yield P-values, so that you want to compare two different ways of calculating P-values (as I assumed in my answer), or are the "methods" data generating methods that have been analyses by a single statistical method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not compare p-values directly. If you want to test if method B is better than method A then you can test method A and B on your same paired data, compute the 3 performance measures and perform a paired test (e.g. a paired t test, wilcoxon sign-rank test, wilcoxon rank-sum test, etc.) depending of the type of your data. Since you are doing multiple comparisons (in this case 3 metrics) you may need to correct your p-values for example with a bonferroni correction.

Comment: 'Correction' for multiplicity of comparisons seems to be irrelevant to the question. Why do you suggest it for this case?

Comment: @MichaelLew I suggested it because 3 tests would be needed, one for each of the performance metrics. Each test has an associated type 1 error which is the significance level of the test, e.g., 0.05. in which case 1 out of 20 times you would expect to reject the null hypothesis when in fact it is true. With 3 tests you are more likely to reject the null hypothesis of one of of them when in fact the null is true. This was my reasoning for suggesting a correction but let me know if it does not make sense or if i am missing something.

Comment: I am now thinking that I may have misunderstood the original question. See my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know whether the null hypotheses of the three pairs of tests are true or not then I doubt that you will be able to determine whether one test performs better than the other using those three pairs of P-values. However, assuming both tests perform appropriately when the null hypothesis is true, and that you know the null is false for all of the cases where you have P-values, the method that gives lower P-values is more powerful. I don't know how to perform a hypothesis test for test powers.